# Excel vba random function

Tags: vba, excel

There is a `Application.Worksheetfunction.RandBetween(0, 1)`, but it only returns a whole number: 0 or 1, while I need a not whole numberr between 0 and 1.

What is a equivalent of worksheet function `Rand()`?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The worksheet function should be `=RAND(0,10000)/10000`. You can adjust the number of decimal places in this way.

The VBA equivalent might look like this function. Determine the number of digits by means of the argument.

```
Function RandomNumber(ByVal Digits As Integer) As Double

    Dim Fun As Double

    Randomize
    Fun = Rnd
    RandomNumber = Round(Fun, Digits)
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I have written this Function pretty long ago and if I need a random number i normally can generate it easily this way.

Note that you need the Randomize-Statement to make sure, that the random creates a new set of random numbers each time you use the function.

```
Private Function random(minval As Integer, maxval As Integer, _
    Optional decimalaccuracy As Integer = 10000) As Double

    Randomize
    random = (maxval - minval + 1) * Rnd + minval
    If decimalaccuracy <> 10000 Then random = _
        Application.WorksheetFunction.Round(random, decimalaccuracy)

End Function
```

Comment: Fair enough - don't know why it displayed it a minute a go

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    Sub rndNumber()
        Dim rNum As Double

             Randomize
             rNum = Format(Rnd(1), "#0.00")
    End Sub
```

check [randomise](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/randomize.php) function

Answer (score 0):

`Rnd()` is the VBA equivalent of the formula `RAND()`.

Example Usage:

```
Dim rand1 As Double
'Initialize the random number generator.
Randomize
rand1 = Rnd()
```